# Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, enterprise-library

I am working on migrating the current ASP.NET application from 2.0 to 4.0 and also trying to migrate the enterprise library to 5.0 from 4.0

I have made all the necessary changes in the configuration file. All the application is working on project mates machine but it is not working on my machine.

Stack Trace of the error I am getting ---

```
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type LogWriter, key ""
  Source=Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
       at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService]()
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.get_Writer()
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Write(LogEntry log)
       at App.LogEntryHelper.WriteLogEntry(LogEntry entry, String category) in c:\App.Client.WebUI\AppCode\LogEntryHelper.cs:line 252
       at App.LogEntryHelper.WriteFacadePerformanceLog(DateTime start, DateTime end) in c:\App.Client.WebUI\AppCode\LogEntryHelper.cs:line 209
       at App.Facade.FutureEventFacade.GetFutureEventsParticipant(Int64 participantID) in c:\App.Client.WebUI\Facade\FutureEventFacade.cs:line 92
       at App.Facade.ParticipantFacade.GetParticipant(Int64 participantID) in c:\App.Client.WebUI\Facade\ParticipantFacade.cs:line 81
       at App.ParticipantPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\App.Client.WebUI\ParticipantPage.aspx.cs:line 67
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Adapters.ControlAdapter.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type LogWriter cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter,(none)

       Source=Microsoft.Practices.Unity
       TypeRequested=LogWriter
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
            at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides)
            at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityServiceLocator.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
            at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
       InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
            HResult=-2146233079
            Message=The type LogWriter cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
            Source=Microsoft.Practices.Unity
            StackTrace:
                 at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.GuardTypeIsNonPrimitive(IBuilderContext context, SelectedConstructor selectedConstructor)
                 at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
                 at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
                 at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlanCreatorPolicy.CreatePlan(IBuilderContext context, NamedTypeBuildKey buildKey)
                 at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
                 at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
                 at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
            InnerException:
```

Here are the details of configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="App.Properties.SecuritySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="App.Properties.ReportingSettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="App.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web">
      <section name="uploadManagement" type="App.WebControls.UploadModule, App.WebControls"/>
    </sectionGroup>
    <!-- AJAX -->
    <!-- End AJAX -->
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
    <listeners>
      <add fileName="App.Debug.log" header="----------------------------------------" footer="----------------------------------------" formatter="Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="Debug Flat File TraceListener"/>
      <add fileName="App.Client.WebUI.Facade.Performance.log" header="----------------------------------------" footer="----------------------------------------" formatter="Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="Facade Performance Flat File TraceListener"/>
      <add fileName="App.Exception.log" rollSizeKB="10000" timeStampPattern="ddd" rollFileExistsBehavior="Overwrite" rollInterval="Day" formatter="Text Formatter" header="----------------------------------------" footer="----------------------------------------" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" traceOutputOptions="Callstack" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="Rolling Flat File TraceListener"/>
      <add source="AdminTool Web UI" formatter="Text Formatter" log="AdminTool" machineName="" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" traceOutputOptions="Callstack" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="WebUI EventLog TraceListener"/>
      <add fileName="App.SSO.log" header="----------------------------------------" footer="----------------------------------------" formatter="Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="SSO Flat File TraceListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add template="Timestamp: {timestamp}&#xA;Message: {message}&#xA;Category: {category}&#xA;Priority: {priority}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}&#xA;Severity: {severity}&#xA;Title:{title}&#xA;Machine: {machine}&#xA;Application Domain: {appDomain}&#xA;Process Id: {processId}&#xA;Process Name: {processName}&#xA;Win32 Thread Id: {win32ThreadId}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}&#xA;&#xA;)}" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="Text Formatter"/>
    </formatters>
    <logFilters>
      <add minimumPriority="0" maximumPriority="3" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.PriorityFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="Priority Debug Filter"/>
    </logFilters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="Web UI Debug">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Debug Flat File TraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </add>
      <add switchValue="All" name="Web UI Exception">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File TraceListener"/>
          <add name="WebUI EventLog TraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </add>
      <add switchValue="All" name="Web UI Facade Performance">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Facade Performance Flat File TraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </add>
      <add switchValue="All" name="Web UI SSO">
        <listeners>
          <add name="SSO Flat File TraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events"/>
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Debug Flat File TraceListener"/>
          <add name="WebUI EventLog TraceListener"/>
          <add name="SSO Flat File TraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </notProcessed>
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings"/>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <exceptionHandling>
    <exceptionPolicies>
      <add name="WebUI Policy">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add type="System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException, System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" postHandlingAction="None" name="DirectoryServicesCOMException"/>
          <add type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" postHandlingAction="None" name="Exception">
            <exceptionHandlers>
              <add logCategory="Web UI Exception" eventId="2000" severity="Error" title="Enterprise Library Exception Handling" formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" priority="0" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="Logging Handler"/>
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
    </exceptionPolicies>
  </exceptionHandling>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is different issue than the link you provided.

Comment: Can you show your unity.config file? Does it have ent.library extension  registered? I mean clearly exception is the same as in other question I provided, but since it is working on other machine - probably some assembly registration is missing in GAC?

Comment: Alexander, I tried to check the GAC assemblies and kept exactly same assemblies as other working machine have.

Comment: Here is the configuration section --

Comment: I have updated the details with the configuration file details. What do you mean by "Does it have ent.library extension registered?"

Answer (score 2):

I am able to resolve the issue. I found that I have installed version of ESB 2.0 which was causing the issue. Whenever application is trying to log something IIS used to look into the ESB configuration file instead of web.config file. As soon as I uninstalled the ESB application everything started working.

Answer (score 2):

For me I was opening another configuration file which had the enterpriseLibrary but it was missing from the local app configuration file.  I added the following into the local configuration and I got past the error.

```
  <configSections>
       <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" requirePermission="true" />
 </configSections>
```